# Using lldb to display function outparam results

Tags: lldb

I'm currently debugging with lldb a very large application and I'm interested in all the calls to some function (here, `pthread_create`). I want to know the call stack and the result of all these calls, which is passed as an out argument.

Getting the call stack is simple:

```
break set pthread_create
break command add 1.1
  bt
  continue
  DONE
```

However, I'd like to also print the result of every single call to this function (preferably just after the `bt`).

In effect, I basically would like to replace the implementation of

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine)(void *), void *arg);
```

to:

- run the original `pthread_create`;
- display the value of `thread`;
- display the backtrace;
- return from `pthread_create` as usual.

Will lldb let me do this?

Answer (score 3):

Another solution to this problem is to make a custom step type that does what you want.  The last example (FinishPrintAndContinue) in

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/lldb/examples/python/scripted_step.py

does a finish from the current frame, and then prints the value of `rax`.  You can get it to print whatever you want at that point.

The example continues when the "finish" is done, but you can change that by returning True from the "should_stop" once the finish plan you've pushed is complete.

You would use this by doing:

```
(lldb) thread step-scripted -C scripted_step.FinishPrintAndContinue
```

That's a bit of a mouthful, but if you use this often, just make an alias for it:

```
(lldb) command alias fancy-step thread step-scripted -C scripted-step.FinishPrintAndContinue
```

Then you can just say:

```
(lldb) fancy-step
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use lldb's user defined variables. From `help expression`:

> User defined variables:
>
> ```
> You can define your own variables for convenience or to be used in subsequent
> expressions.  You define them the same way you would define variables in C.
> If the first character of your user defined variable is a $, then the
> variable's value will be available in future expressions, otherwise it will
> just be available in the current expression.
> ```

In your example, you would create a user defined variable named `$thread` to be used later. Then run `finish` (aka `thread step-out`) to complete `pthread_create`. At this point, running `p $thread` will show you the thread that was created by the function.

The resulting breakpoint command would look like:

```
p pthread_t *$thread = (pthread_t *)$arg1
finish
p *$thread
bt
continue
```

The `$arg1` is an lldb alias for the register used to pass the first argument.

#### Update

As pointed out in the comment, using `finish` in a breakpoint command results in "error: Aborting reading of commands after command #2: 'finish' continued the target".

One solution is to use Python to make a custom `finish` command that avoids the issue. This function runs `StepOutOfFrame()`, but before doing so it puts lldb in synchronous mode. I have tested this with lldb-1100.0.30.12 from Xcode 11.3.1.

```py
import lldb

@lldb.command("Finish")
def finish(debugger, expression, context, result, _internal):
    is_async = debugger.GetAsync()
    debugger.SetAsync(False)
    context.thread.StepOutOfFrame(context.frame)
    debugger.SetAsync(is_async)
```

In your `~/.lldbinit`, import this script:

```
command script import path/to/finish.py
```

Now instead of `finish` in the breakpoint command, use the custom `Finish` command (capitalized name to not overwrite the built-in `finish`).

Comment: Thanks!
I needed to replace `= $arg1` with `= (pthread_t*)$arg1`.
Unfortunately, I get
```
error: Aborting reading of commands after command #2: 'finish' continued the target.
```

Comment: @Yoric I added an alternative finish command using python, hopefully that works for you.

Comment: Thanks, it nearly works :) I've learnt many things from this!
Unfortunately, I realized that the thread ID I'm looking for is actually the one I get from `pthread_threadid_np`. Any attempt to use this within the breakpoint command results in  `error: Aborting reading of commands after command #5: 'p (int)pthread_threadid_np(*$thread, &$id)' failed with error: DoExecute called with no thread selected`, even if I add a `thread select 1`.